# Vue Component Functionality with Conditional Rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a `vue` component called [`<PlanView/>`](https://gricad-gitlab.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/pacbot_group/GUI_pacbot/-/blob/devel/src/views/PlanView.vue), and I'm rendering this component conditionally:

```html
<div v-if="show_plan" id="mainplan">
  <PlanView/>
</div>
<div class="icon" v-else>
  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-angles-right" @click="openPlan"/>
</div>
```

```js
openPlan() {
    this.show_plan = true;
},
```

but I want the functionality to be called even if the component is not rendered, can you please advise me how can I do that? thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by calling the functionality without rendering component?

Comment: @Nitheesh '*calling the functionality*' in my case is to call the sub-components without parsing them on the GUI.

Comment: what does this "functionality" refer to? I mean reading your code, I can understand that it will show the icon if `show_plan === false` and show the `PlantView` if `show_plan === true`, and that if you click the icon it will show the component, but what exactly do you want here? can you explain more?

Comment: Could you please describe *calling the sub-components* more detailed? Your code is not full enough to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the component to be renedered and not displayed, you can hide the visibility of the template inside the component rather than hiding the complete compoenent.

Pass a prop to `PlanView` to decide the template is to be rendered or not

```
<PlanView :showPlan="show_plan"/>
```

Accept the prop inside `PlanView` component like

```
defineProps({
    showPlan: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: false,
        default: false
    }
})
```

Render the template of `PlanView` only if the prop is satisfied. So the template of `PlanView` will be looking like

```
<template>
    <!-- Div or some wraper element -->
    <div v-if="showPlan"> 
        <!-- Rest of your template here -->
    </div>
</template>
```

**OR**

Simply use `v-show` on the wrapper so that the element will be loaded, but will not be displayed in the UI when the condition is false

```
<PlanView v-show="show_plan"/>
```

Comment: for this use case, I think it's better to just use `<PlantView v-show="show_plan">` imo

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `v-show` instead of `v-if` to provide the same functionality as the answer from @Nitheesh suggests.

```
<div v-show="show_plan" id="mainplan">
  <PlanView/>
</div>
<div v-show="!show_plan" class="icon">
  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-angles-right" @click="openPlan"/>
</div>
```

But I am not sure this is what you means by *by calling the functionality*.